# How to change @react-navigation/drawer DrawerItemList's style

Tags: css, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm using [@react-navigation/drawer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation).

And it is very annoying with the style inside `<DrawerContentScrollView>`

I have [demo here](https://snack.expo.dev/@zhenguet/drawer-demo) ( please run on andorid, on web do not have the paddingTop )

The problem: [image: ![problem]

Inside the view in DrawerContentScrollView has a style:

```
{
  "paddingTop": 34.18181800842285,
  "paddingStart": 0,
  "paddingEnd": 0
}
```

It's good if I don't customize a header at the top. It seems StatusBar's padding. I don't know where to fix it. I want to turn it off or change the paddingTop: 0.

[image: want to remove]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

add **[contentContainerStyle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/drawer-navigator/#contentcontainerstyle)={{paddingTop: 0}}** into `<DrawerContentScrollView>`

```
<DrawerContentScrollView
  {...props}
  contentContainerStyle={{paddingTop: 0}}>
  <DrawerItemList {...props} />
</DrawerContentScrollView>
```

Comment: This is good but would love to see also how to edit the Item styles individually as well as asked (although actually not needed for this solution)

Comment: Either define the drawer entries by using DrawerItem component, or define options props inside your Drawer screens, and then use DrawerContent or DrawerItemList compoments